# Score and Text-Box Moving Above Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below which when i executed in iphone/android devices, the score, text-boxes is moving above the screen, when i enter the text in the text boxes. i want the screen to be constant when i write the text in the boxes.

```
<div id="score">score: 0</div>
<input type="text" id="question" />
<input type="text" id="question1" />



 <script>
    var answers = {
        'question': 'yes',
        'question1': 'no'
    };
    var score = 0;
    function checkResults() {
        var $this = $(this), val = $this.val().toLowerCase();
        for (var k in answers) {
            if (answers.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                if (answers[$this.attr('id')] && answers[$this.attr('id')] === val) {
                    score += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        $('#score').text('score: ' + score);
    }
    $('input').on('keyup', checkResults);
</script>
```

Comment: can you share the css

Comment: No css. i'm just running on my iphone but when i touch text box to write, its going up and returning to normal view when i dont enter any text...